# Toggle icon in an entry of dropdown menu while the dropdown is open

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I am trying to display a list of files for playback and would like to allow the user to listen to them while selecting. I am using a DropdownButton to display the optional files.
When the list is closed and i hit the play/stop icon, the icon is updated and displays correctly according to the state (playing/stopped).
When the list is open the state is toggled but the icon doesnt get updated in the open list.
How can i achieve this?
I have tried using DropdownButton2 package. It is slightly better, it does updated the icon in the selected line but not next to any of the open items in the list.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleItemListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleItemListView({super.key,});

  static const routeName = '/';

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SampleItemListViewState();
}

class SampleItemListViewState extends State<SampleItemListView> {

  final List<String> items = const ['10', '20', '30'];
  bool isPlaying = false;
  String selectedItem = '10';

  @override
  void initState() {    
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Items'),
      ),

      body: DropdownButtonFormField(
          value: selectedItem,
          onChanged: (value) async {
            selectedItem = value.toString();
          },
        items: items
          .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
          value: e,
          child: SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      setState(() {
                        isPlaying = !isPlaying;                                               
                      });
                    },
                    icon: isPlaying ? 
                      const Icon(Icons.stop_circle) : 
                      const Icon(Icons.play_arrow)),
                  const Spacer(),
                  Expanded(child: Text(e.toString())),
                ]
                )
            )))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StatefulBuilder` because it has a own state and you can rebuild their local state

```
class SampleItemListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleItemListView({
    super.key,
  });

  static const routeName = '/';

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SampleItemListViewState();
}

class SampleItemListViewState extends State<SampleItemListView> {
  final List<String> items = const ['10', '20', '30'];
  bool isPlaying = false;
  String selectedItem = '10';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Items'),
      ),
      body: DropdownButtonFormField(
        value: selectedItem,
        onChanged: (value) async {
          selectedItem = value.toString();
        },
        items: items
            .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: e,
                /// You can use StatefulBuilder
                child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, menuState) {
               return   SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                      child: Row(children: [
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              menuState(() {
                                isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                              });
                            },
                            icon: isPlaying ? const Icon(Icons.stop_circle) : const Icon(Icons.play_arrow)),
                        const Spacer(),
                        Expanded(child: Text(e.toString())),
                      ]));
                })))
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Does not require another widget

Comment: How can i ensure that only one item from the list is displaying the playing icon. When i click on a button the icon changes as it should, but if i had another entry which is already playing, its icon wont change back.

Answer (score 2):

You need a boolean for every ıtem of your list to do that model is needed, and set uı in DropdownMenuItem you need to declare stateful widget for its child,
Here is a working version of your code.

```
class SampleItemListView extends StatefulWidget {
const SampleItemListView({
super.key,
});

static const routeName = '/';

@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() => SampleItemListViewState();
```

}

```
class SampleItemListViewState extends State<SampleItemListView> {
List<ItemModel> items = [
  ItemModel(data: '10', isPlaying: false),
  ItemModel(data: '20', isPlaying: false),
  ItemModel(data: '30', isPlaying: false),
];

late ItemModel? selectedItem;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  selectedItem = items[0];
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Sample Items'),
    ),
    body: DropdownButtonFormField(
      value: items[0],
      onChanged: (value) async {
        selectedItem = value;
        setState(() {});
      },
      items: items
          .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: e,
                child: ItemWidget(
                  item: e,
                  onStateChanged: () {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final ItemModel item;
  final VoidCallback onStateChanged;

  const ItemWidget({
  Key? key,
  required this.item,
  required this.onStateChanged,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<ItemWidget> createState() => _ItemWidgetState();
}

class _ItemWidgetState extends State<ItemWidget> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: 100,
    child: Row(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              widget.item.isPlaying = !widget.item.isPlaying;
            });
            widget.onStateChanged();
          },
          icon: widget.item.isPlaying ? const Icon(Icons.stop_circle) : 
          const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          Expanded(child: Text(widget.item.data)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class ItemModel {
  bool isPlaying;
  String data;

  ItemModel({required this.isPlaying, required this.data});
}
```

Comment: Answers the need. The solution by @rasityilmaz is simpler.